# Creating a type using Pick with a type that is defined as a union of types

Tags: typescript, material-ui, mui-x

I'm trying to create a type that simplifies an existing interface.  The existing type comes from `@mui/x-data-grid`.  The type is

```js
export declare type GridEnrichedColDef<R extends GridValidRowModel = any, V = any, F = V> = GridColDef<R, V, F> | GridActionsColDef<R, V, F>;
```

The properties I'd like to support are

```
export type SupportedColumnProps =
  | 'field'
  | 'headerName'
  | 'width'
  | 'renderCell'
  | 'valueFormatter'
  | 'flex'
  | 'sortable'
  | 'hide'
  | 'type'
  | 'cellClassName';
```

as well as the `getActions` property if the `type` property is set to `'actions'`.  But when I try something like `Pick<GridEnrichedColDef, SupportedColumnProps | 'getActions'> I can't get the type to recognize that it sometimes should allow` getActions`(when`type`is`'actions'`).

How can I create this type to simplify the interface and provide good defaults?

Thanks!

## Update 1/30/2023

I have the following defined based on @Oblosys's answer:

```js
export type SupportedColumnProps =
  | 'field'
  | 'headerName'
  | 'width'
  | 'renderCell'
  | 'renderHeader'
  | 'valueFormatter'
  | 'flex'
  | 'sortable'
  | 'hide'
  | 'type'
  | 'cellClassName'
  | 'editable'
  | 'getActions'
  | 'valueOptions';

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75271774/creating-a-type-using-pick-with-a-type-that-is-defined-as-a-union-of-types/75290368#75290368
type KeyOfUnion<T> = T extends unknown ? keyof T : never;
type PickUnion<T, K extends KeyOfUnion<T>> = T extends unknown
  ? K & keyof T extends never
    ? never
    : Pick<T, K>
  : never;
export type GridColumn = PickUnion<GridEnrichedColDef, SupportedColumnProps> & { enableColumnMenu?: boolean };
```

However, now it seems like if I define a column without `type` or `getActions`, it says my object doesn't satisfy this type.  For example:

```js
const column: GridColumn = {
  field: 'hello'
}
```

[image]

Comment: You could use distribution to apply `Pick` to each union member, like this: https://tsplay.dev/mZQpDN Would that work for your use case?

Comment: This is awesome.  I haven't run across this concept called distribution before, I don't think.  But I look forward to learning more about.  I'm still trying this out but it seems to be working so far!

One thing I'm sort of contemplating is a way to keep the `SupportedColumnProps` "type-safe" but as soon as I try something like `Extract<keyof GridEnrichedColDef, '...' | ...>`, it no longer likes `getActions` again.  But it would be nice to know that the `SuportedColumnProps` union had the correct strings in it.

Comment: It's straightforward to constrain the `K` parameter to the keys in the union, I can write up an answer tomorrow if you like.

Comment: If you would, and you have the time for it, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: If I change `DistributionPick<T, K>` to be `DistributionPick<T, K extends keyof GridEnrichedColDef>`, I'm back to the same error where it really doesn't trust that "sometimes" `getActions` is an allowed property name.  There is something fundamental about this that I'm misunderstanding...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When applied to a union, `Pick` behaves slightly different from what you might expect. One issue is that `Pick` has a `K extends keyof T` constraint, and for a union, `keyof` only returns keys that are present in *each* union member, so you cannot pick a property that only exists on some of the union members. Moreover, `Pick` applied to a union yields a single object with union property values rather than a union of objects (i.e. `Pick<{a: number} | {a: string}, 'a'>` evaluates to `{a: number | string}` instead of `{a: number} | {a: string}`).

To tackle the first problem, you can use a dummy `extends` clause to define a *distributive conditional type* ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)) that applies `keyof` to each union member and returns a union of the results:

```
type KeyOfUnion<T> = T extends unknown ? keyof T : never

type Test = KeyOfUnion<{a: number, b: boolean} | {b: string, c: symbol}>
// type Test = "a" | "b" | "c"
```

Using `KeyOfUnion` in the constraint, you can use another distributive conditional type to apply `Pick` to each union member while using an intersection to only pick appropriate keys:

```
type PickUnionNaive<T, K extends KeyOfUnion<T>> =
  T extends unknown ? Pick<T, K & keyof T> : never

type Test = PickUnionNaive<{a: number, b: boolean} | {a: string}, 'a'>
// type Test = PickUnionNaive<{a: number, b: boolean}, "a"> | PickUnion<{a: string}, "a">
// which evaluates to: {a: number} | {a: string}
```

However, this type has a problem with keys that are not shared by all union members, as these will introduce empty `{}` types in the union by picking with `never` as the key parameter.

```
type Test = PickUnionNaive<{a: number, b: boolean} | {a: string}, 'b'>
// type Test = Pick<{a: number, b: boolean}, "b"> | Pick<{a: string}, never>
// which evaluates to: {b: boolean} | {}
```

This is problematic as it basically turns the resulting union into `{}`, and any type can be assigned to `{}`. To get rid of the empty objects, you can add an extra conditional to yield `never` if intersection between the keys to pick and the keys of the union member is empty, which leads to this definition of `PickUnion`:

```
type PickUnion<T, K extends KeyOfUnion<T>> =
  T extends unknown
  ? K & keyof T extends never ? never : Pick<T, K & keyof T>
  : never

type Test = PickUnion<{a: number, b: boolean} | {a: string}, 'b'>
// type Test = {b: boolean}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://tsplay.dev/wQYovw)

Comment: You are the real MVP.  I have a lot of studying to do with this solution, but I really do appreciate the help!

Comment: After applying your solution, I'm noticing that now any GridColumn I've defined that doesn't specify the `type` or `getActions` properties fail to satisfy the type.  I'll update my question with the latest

Comment: @JakeSmith The solution needed an extra intersection to avoid picking invalid keys. Should be fixed now.

Comment: I'm still having issues.  With the changes you made most recently, now I can't have a column object with `getActions` at all.

Comment: sike, my mistake.  This looks like it is working!